# Fireworks CS4: Creating/Adding Guides

Tags: adobe-fireworks, ruler

How do I create a guide for every 18 pixels? It's too tiresome to manually create them for a project with 1500px.

Comment: Why did you make this community wiki. Although it might not belong here, it still did not need to be made CW.

Comment: I don't even know how I made this into a community wiki. How do I turn this into a regular question?

Answer (score 0):

Just turn on an 18 pixel grid instead of guidelines. Much easier.

Comment: Yeah did that horizontally but the vertical ones need to have a grid/guide for every 40px with a additional 1px guide before and after the 40px grid.